Nuxt Middleware not firing outside of development server
I am trying to call a News API when the user goes to the the news page. I would usually use asyncData or fetch to call the API, but the API is handled by their client and I kept running into CORS issues. The client seemed pretty adamant that they did not need to change anything on their side, so I tried to find a workaround.
I opted to use Nuxt middleware to call the API and add the news to a store, which the page can use.
fetchNews.js in middleware
export default async function ({ $axios, store }) {
  try {
    const data = await $axios.$get(
      'https://www.futurehumber.com/api/investment-news.json'
    ) // Adjust the endpoint as necessary
    store.commit('setNews', data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error)
  }
}

and then in the page
middleware: 'fetchNews',

I then load like so:
loadNewPage(pageNumber: number): void {
      if (!this.$store.state.news.data) return
      this.items = this.$store.state.news.data.slice(
        (pageNumber - 1) * this.perPage,
        pageNumber * this.perPage
      )
      this.meta = this.$store.state.news.meta
    },

mounted() {
    this.loadNewPage(1)
  },

On intial load, the news items do not appear, but after a reload they do. When deployed to a staging site, the middleware is not re-run on page loads, so any new news items do not appear.
The site is targeting static.
